# Redirection 302 for PUT request via Shopify API

Tags: python, redirect, get, shopify, http-status-code-302

**Set-up**

I'm using the [Shopify Admin API](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api) Python library to access our shops via a private app connection.

GET requests work fine, i.e. `product = shopify.Product.find(6514193137813)` retrieves the product data.

---

**Issue**

If I want to update an existing product, PUT requests don't work. That is,

```
product.title = 'test123'
product.save()
```

returns a `Redirection: Response(code=302,...)`.

---

**So far**

I've double-checked and read and write permission are on.

Then I found this question on the Shopify forum: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/API-Fulfillment-Status-Code-302-Redirect/m-p/747383/highlight/true#, where Shopify staff member hassain indicates that *Shopify prevents you from using HTTP Basic Auth for POST requests that have cookies*.

But since his statement is about POST requests, I'm not sure this is relevant.

How do I make the PUT request work?

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'm having a similar issue with Fulfillements

Comment: Not yet, I'm afraid...

Comment: as far as your problem are you able to update other parts of the product aside from title?

Comment: Not able to make any put requests. I've opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/issues/469

Comment: Try requests instead of that library to test if its a coding issue or configuration issue.This code worked for me. https://jsfiddle.net/g2z97wc0/

Comment: Yes mate, you're a life's saver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [MalcolmInTheCenter's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2609521/malcolminthecenter) comment and successfully updated the product using his request code,

```
import requests

payload = {
           "product":{
                      "title":"My new title"
                      }
           }

api_key = "xxxxx"
password="xxxxxx"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

#send email to customer through events endpoint
r = requests.put("https://"+api_key+":"+password+"@MYSTORE.myshopify.com//admin/api/2021-01/products/{PRODUCT_ID}.json", json=payload,  headers=headers)
print(r)
```

Comment: Awesome. That python library is not the best for Shopify use. Very little documentation and not easy to use.